# CefSharp - accessing chromium Dev Tools with code (network tab)

Tags: c#, .net, cefsharp

I have a CefSharp window in my WinForms app and I'd like to access the network tab in dev tools and copy some stuff from there (like loading times, URLs...). Is that possible with CefSharp? Or is there any other browser implementation for C# that will allow me to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_ShowDevTools_1.htm

Comment: That opens the dev tools just like in chrome, but I need to access the data with my c# code

Comment: Supported for directly accessing DevTools was added in version 83, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3158 this is a very new feature and examples are limited at this point. See also https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2961/add-support-for-direct-communication-over#comment-57838380 which has details on enabling logging Devtools commands. https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Network/#event-dataReceived

Comment: Oh that's nice! Did you find any examples? It would help a lot

Comment: You need to implement http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/T_CefSharp_Callback_IDevToolsMessageObserver.htm then register the observer then enable the set of events that you, at least that's my understanding at this point. http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_AddDevToolsMessageObserver.htm  http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_GetBrowserHost.htm an example of taking a screenshot linked in the GitHub issue. https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Network/#method-enable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ChromiumWebBrowser cefBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("about:blank");
cefBrowser.ShowDevTools();
```