# Whether the Cefsharp can get the amount of data transferred like Devtools?

Tags: c#, .net, cefsharp, devtools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/butpQ.png)

the network tab of devtools can calculate the amount of data transferred over network
how can I get these in cefsharp ?  the IRequestHandler or IResourceRequestHandler only can get the length
data, but it's resource size, not transferred over network.
I want to count traffic consumption of a webpage in cefsharp

Comment: You can directly access DevTools, this is a new feature. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782579/cefsharp-accessing-chromium-dev-tools-with-code-network-tab#comment111025640_62782579 has some details. Which data in DevTools are you after exactly?

Comment: the amount of data transferred

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2961/add-support-for-direct-communication-over#comment-57838380 has details on how to enable logging for Devtools, you need to identify the commands and events required

Comment: Are there any example about how to use the new feature?  I  implement the IDevToolsMessageObserver, but i don't know how to register the observer .

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3158#issuecomment-651004911

Comment: i have read the example and the https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3) . the cefsharp allow you executeDevToolsMethod , but how can i listern to the Devtools' event?   Getting the amount of data transferred need the DevTools Protocol Event : Network.responseReceived / Network.loadingFinished

Comment: You need to call https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Network/#method-enable I'd strongly suggest you enable logging as I've linked above so you get a better understanding of how the protocol works

Comment: Great, you can answer your own question so others can benefit.